# adding more values to a list on existing python dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

I am a beginner in python and want to do implement something like this:

the values in a the dict is a list. if key already exists in dict then append to the list of values. if key not present, then add the key-value pair. the values field is a list and i need to append one value at a time to the list.

```
d = { x: [1,2,3,4]
      y : [5,6,7,8] }
```

if now z is next key, since its not present, we add it to the dict and the corresponding value. for another key-value(say x: 9), dict should be:

```
d = {x : [1,2,3,4,9]
     y : [5,6,7,8]
     z : [10] 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to create a dict that has empty list as the default value:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
d['x'] = [1,2,3,4]
d['y'] = [5,6,7,8]
# d is {'y': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'x': [1, 2, 3, 4]}

d['z'].append(10)
d['x'].append(9)
print d
# d is now {'y': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'x': [1, 2, 3, 4, 9], 'z': [10]}
```

Note that this works because `list` is a built-in function that creates an empty list.